# Showing summation is bounded

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm currently taking a Comp Sci class that is reviewing Calculus 2. I have a question:

Show that the summation $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i^2}$ is bounded above by a constant

I realize that this question is already answered here

[Showing that the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{k^2}$ is bounded by a constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436636/showing-that-the-summation-is-bounded-by-a-constant#)

Could anyone explain it to me further? I believe I'm supposed to use p-series test or integral test to complete

Comment: I think the answer in that link is pretty clear...

Comment: Can you clarify what you don't understand about the linked answer?

Comment: @anorton, I highly doubt this question would be interesting in the least  for anyone that could "say" that the infinite series gotten from the finite one by taking the limit $\;n\to\infty\;$ is $\;\zeta(2)\;$ ...

Comment: You seem to have knowledge of the integral test - why didn't you simply apply that? It shows very quickly that the sum converges, and hence is bounded above.

Comment: If you are interested also in the value of the sum, see here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1n2

Comment: These question are also related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58931/does-sum-limits-k-1n-1-k-2-converge-when-n-rightarrow-infty and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333417/need-to-prove-the-sequence-a-n-1-frac122-frac132-cdots-frac1n

Comment: @anorton: No biggie!

Answer (score 6):

You can try the following, pretty similar to that link's, approach:

$$\frac1{k^2}\le\frac1{k(k-1)}=\frac1{k-1}-\frac1k\implies$$

$$\sum_{k=2}^N\frac1{k^2}\le\sum_{k=2}^N\left(\frac1{k-1}-\frac1k\right)=1-\frac12+\frac12-\frac13+\frac13-\frac14+\ldots+\frac1{N-1}-\frac1N=$$

$$=1-\frac1N\le 1$$

and you've proved boundedness for **any** $\;N\in\Bbb N$

**Notes:**  Observe that in the above we take the sum from $\;n=2\;$ and not, as you did, from $\;n=1\;$ . Answer:

(1) Why?

(2) Explain why the above doesn't affect the boundedness of the original series.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i^2} = 1 + \sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{i^2} \leq 1 + \int_{1}^{n}\frac{dx}{x^2}= 2 - \frac{1}{n}\leq 2,\, \quad \forall n\in \mathbb{N}.$$