# Why $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i} =\mathcal O(\ln(n))$?

Tags: summation

I am reading textbook proof on algorithms that uses this fact:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i} =\mathcal O(\ln(n)).$$

Why is that true? I'm trying to use Taylor series to find out why, but I'm not making much progress.

Comment: ln(x) is the integral of the function 1/x, bounding the sum

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant

Comment: Here is a [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655492/showing-summation-is-bounded/655638#655638).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For every nonincreasing function $u$ and every $k$,
$$
\int_{k}^{k+1}u(x)\,\mathrm dx\leqslant u(k)\leqslant \int_{k-1}^ku(x)\,\mathrm dx,
$$
hence
$$
\int_1^{n+1}u(x)\,\mathrm dx\leqslant\sum_{k=1}^nu(k)\leqslant u(1)+\int_1^nu(x)\,\mathrm dx.
$$
If $u:x\mapsto1/x$, the RHS is $1+\log n$ and the LHS is $\log(n+1)$ hence, for every $n\geqslant1$,
$$
\log n\leqslant\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\leqslant1+\log n.
$$
The sum in the middle is called $H_n$ the $n$th harmonic number and one knows that, when $n\to\infty$, $H_n-\log n\to\gamma$ [the Euler constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant), with $\gamma\approx0.577$.

Answer (score 3):

Using Taylor series is working too hard! Recall the definition of $\ln$ (or, at least, a property):
$$\ln(x) = \int_1^x \frac 1xdx$$ 
If $x \in \Bbb N$, we also have from the definition of the integral $$\int_1^x \frac 1x dx \geq \sum_{n=2}^x \frac 1n$$

You can see that pictorially here (picture stolen from [Paul's Online Math Notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/IntegralTest.aspx)):

[image]

We also have $\sum_{n=2}^x \frac 3n \geq \sum_{n=1}^x \frac 1n$ for $n \in \Bbb N$ (which you can prove by induction or otherwise), so that $$3\ln(x) \geq \sum_{n=1}^x \frac 1n$$ and thus $\sum_{n=1}^x \frac 1n = O(\ln(x))$ as desired.