# Prove that $a_{n+1}=a_{n} + 1/(n+1)^2$ is bounded from above

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Prove that $a_{n+1}=a_{n} + 1/(n+1)^2$ is bounded from above

What I have tried is 
$$a_n=1+1/4+\dots+1/n^2\leq 1+1+\dots +1=n$$

So I conclude that $a_n$ is bounded above by $n$.
Does this sufficient to say that the sequence is bounded from above?
Or it can only be said when the sequence is bounded from above by a constant but not any function of $n$?

Comment: It has to be a constant not dependent on $n$ to be bounded above.

Comment: Exact value of the limit: [Different methods to compute $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1n2)

Comment: Another related question: [Showing that the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{k^2}$ is bounded by a constant](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436636/showing-that-the-sum-sum-k-1n-frac1k2-is-bounded-by-a-constant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Hints***

- In general terms $  a_n = a_1 + \frac 1 3^2 + \frac 1 4^2 + ... + \frac {1}{ (n + 1)^2  }$
- The series $ \sum \frac{1}{n^2} $ converges.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**: $a_{n+1} - a_n = \dfrac{1}{(n+1)^2} < \dfrac{1}{n}- \dfrac{1}{n+1}$. Can you see the teloscoping trick?

Comment: From this I only know that $s_n=a_{n+1}-a_n$ will converge to 0.

Answer (score 0):

No, you proved your sequence is bounded by another sequence, you have to prove there is a real number which your sequence never exceeds.

The series in your example is sometimes called the [p-series with $p=2$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29#P-series)

Answer (score 0):

I assume $a_0:=0$. As noted in the comments, your upper bound is not a constant. To get a constant, just put more terms in the sum. Precisely, take the upper bound to be
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}.
$$
*Note:* You don't really need to know the [value of this series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem), all you need to know is that it converges to some number $\alpha$ and take that $\alpha$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $a_{n+1} - a_{n}=\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$, so this is P-series (in this case $p=2$, your problem turns out to  [Basel problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem)